Number of Hamiltonian paths and cycles in complete graphs
So I just learned about Hamiltonian paths and cycles (HP's and HC's), and I am working on finding the total number of such paths and cycles in $K_{n}$ and $K_{n,n}$. I want to verify my work is correct before I check my answers.
In $K_{n}$, there are $\frac{P(n,k)}{2}$ distinct paths with $k$ vertices, and $\frac{P(n,k)}{2k}$ distinct cycles with $k$ vertices. Plugging in $k=n$ gives $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ distinct HC's and $\frac{n!}{2}$ distinct HP's in $K_{n}$.
Now in $K_{n,n}$, we have $\frac{n^2(n-1)^2(n-2)^2...2^21^2}{2}$ = $\frac{(n!)^2}{2}$ distinct HP's. Basically we have two sides from which to select vertices, and we divide by 2 since the forwards and backwards directions are the same. As for the number of distinct HC's, we just divide by $n$, since the starting vertex does not matter. So we have $\frac{(n!)^2}{2n}$ = $\frac{n!(n-1)!}{2}$ distinct HC's.
Is all this correct?

For the HCs in $K_{n,n}$, let the two parts of the vertex set be $V={v_1, \ldots, v_n}$ and $W= {w_1, \ldots, w_n}$. Then there are $n \choose 2$ ways to pick $v_1$’s neighbors. Call them $w_i$ and $w_j$, where $i<j$. Then each of them has one other neighbor, and those two elements of $V \setminus {v_1}$ can be picked in $(n-1)(n-2)$ ways. Then their other neighbors can be picked from $W \setminus {w_i, w_j}$ in $(n-2)(n-3)$ ways, etc. This works out to $\frac{n}{2}(n-1)!^2$ HCs.
